# Does this Auxiliary Fresnel Sum=$\frac1{2\sqrt2\pi}\int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\frac{\pi x}2}\right)\sqrt x}{x^2+1}dx +\frac14 $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, constants, theta-functions, fresnel-integrals

$$\large{\text{Motivation:}}$$

Here is a related Fresnel Integral sum for a seventh in a series of a sum of just a single function:

> [On $$\mathrm{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(C(n)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt2}\right)+ \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(S(n)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt2}\right)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223393/on-mathrm-sum-limits-n-0-infty-leftcn-frac-sqrt-pi2-sqrt2-right)

$$\large{\text{Original Problem and Definitions:}}$$

Here I will use the Normalized definition of the [**Fresnel F and G functions**](https://dlmf.nist.gov/search/search?q=auxiliary%20functions%20for%20Fresnel%20integrals). They are the [auxiliary functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_function#Definition) which means they are used to prove properties about the Fresnel Integrals functions $\text C(x)$ and $\text S(x)$:

Here are the definitions with the problem:

$$\sum_{\Bbb N^0}( \text G(n)+i\text F(n))\\\mathop=^\text{def} i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac12-\int_0^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)dn\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)- \left(\frac12-\int_0^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)dn\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right) \right] \\+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac12-\int_0^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)dn\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)+ \left(\frac12-\int_0^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)dn\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right) \right] \\ = i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\left(\frac12-\text S(n)\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right) -\left(\frac12-\text S(n)\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)\right]\\+  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac12-\text C(n)\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right) +\left(\frac12-\text S(n)\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)\right] $$

$$\large{\text{Visualization:}}$$

Here is a plot of the summand:
[image]

I am more interested in the following summations of which the Fresnel F sum diverges and the Fresnel F sum  converges. [Here are the sums up to thousands of terms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum++i+fresnelF%28x%29%2BfresnelG%28x%29+from+0+to+4000):

$$\sum_0^\infty \text G(n)≈0.581217…$$ and
$$\sum_0^\infty \text F(n)=\infty$$

$$\large{\text{Useful Identity:}}$$

but there is one nice result using [DLMF $7.7.12$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7#E12) proven true [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Re%28exp%28-i+pi+n%5E2%2F2%29%281%2F2+%2B+i%2F2%29+%281+%2B+i+erfi%28%281%2F2+%2B+i%2F2%29+sqrt%28%CF%80%29+n%29%29%29-fresnelG%28n%29)

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \text G(n)+i \text F(n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\frac{i\pi n^2}2}\int_n^\infty e^{\frac{i\pi t^2}2}dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\frac{i\pi n^2}2}\left(\frac12+\frac i2-\text C(n)-i\text S(n)\right)\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty \text G(n)= \text{Re}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\frac{i\pi n^2}2}\left(\frac12+\frac i2-\text C(n)-i\text S(n)\right)=\text{Re} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\frac{i\pi n^2}2}\left(\frac12+\frac i2\bigg)\bigg(1+i\text{erfi}\left((1+i)\frac{\sqrt\pi}2n\right)\right)$$

which can be [put in terms of the Floor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255028/how-to-evaluate-sum-limits-x-0-infty-texterfcx-1-16199904794712636353) or take the real part of the result and use [Euler’s Formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

$$\large{\text{Integral Representation:}}$$

or try evaluating:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \text F(n)=\frac1{\pi\sqrt2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt t (t^2+1) e^{\frac{\pi n^2 t}2}}dt= \frac1{\pi\sqrt 2} \int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{\sqrt t (t^2+1)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\frac{\pi n^2 t}2}dt =   \frac1{2\sqrt2\pi}\int_0^\infty  \frac{\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\frac{\pi t}2}\right)+1}{(t^2+1)\sqrt t}dt=\infty$$

which [diverges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F2+%281+%2B+EllipticTheta%283%2C+0%2C+e%5E%28-%28%CF%80+t%29%2F2%29%29%29%2F%28sqrt+t%28t%5E2%2B1%29%29+from+.001+to+infinity).

$$\large{\text{Updated Problem:}}$$

So now our goal is:
$$\sum_0^\infty \text G(n)$$
Here is an interesting and [convergent integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%282+pi+sqrt+2%29sqrt%28t%29%281+%2B+EllipticTheta%283%2C++e%5E%28-%28%CF%80+t%29%2F2%29%29%29%2F%28%28t%5E2%2B1%29%29+from+0+to+infinity). It has the increasing function of $\sqrt t$ in the numerator strangely making it converge:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \text G(n)\mathop=^\text{def} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac12-\text C(n)\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right) +\left(\frac12-\text S(n)\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)\right]=\frac1{\pi\sqrt2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt t}{ (t^2+1)e^{\frac{\pi n^2 t}2}} dt= \frac1{\pi\sqrt 2} \int_0^\infty  \frac{\sqrt t}{ (t^2+1)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\frac{\pi n^2 t}2}dt =   \frac1{2\sqrt2\pi}\int_0^\infty  \frac{\sqrt t\left[\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\frac{\pi t}2}\right)+1\right]}{t^2+1}dt = \frac1{2\sqrt2\pi}\int_0^\infty  \frac{\sqrt t\,\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\frac{\pi t}2}\right)}{t^2+1}dt+ \frac1{2\sqrt2\pi}\int_0^\infty  \frac{\sqrt t}{t^2+1}dt = \frac1{2\sqrt2\pi}\int_0^\infty  \frac{\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\frac{\pi t}2}\right)\sqrt t}{t^2+1}dt +\frac14$$

of which the partial sum has a closed form in terms of the special case [Jacobi Theta functions of the Third Kind $\vartheta_3(0,x)=\vartheta_3(x)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/) which can be put in terms of [**simpler elliptic functions**](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/03/01/02/).

$$\large{\text{Integrand Visualization:}}$$

Here is a plot of $\frac{\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\frac{\pi t}2}\right)\sqrt t}{t^2+1}$:

[image] According to [Wolfram Functions $9.3.3.6.1$](https://functions.wolfram.com/09.03.03.0006.01), we can simplify to:

$$\boxed{\sum_0^\infty \text G(n)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac12-\text C(n)\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right) +\left(\frac12-\text S(n)\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n^2}{2}\right)\right]= \frac1{2\sqrt2\pi}\int_0^\infty  \frac{\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\frac{\pi t}2}\right)\sqrt t}{t^2+1}dt +\frac14 = \frac{\sqrt i}{2\sqrt2\pi}\int_0^\infty  \frac{\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\frac{2i}t}\right)}{t^2+1}dt +\frac14 }$$

$$\large{\text{Conclusion}}$$

How can I evaluate the Normalized Fresnel G sum? If there is a closed form, then please write it, but it is optional. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ and use $n$ in the upper limits of integration, right? As it stands, you've left the index of summation ambiguous and overloaded the letter $x$, which is pointlessly rebellious and reading it is like scrubbing my brain with sandpaper.

Comment: @runway44 If only used one variable,$x$ in this case, then you can assume that $$\sum_a^b \text{sequence}_n=\sum_{n=a}^b \text{sequence}_n,\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_{x=a}^{x=b} f(x)dx$$ because there is no ambiguity on the variable of the sum nor integral, which uses a differential telling with respect to which variable. It is easier to type and $x$ is still a variable that can be used, like most other operations. How could I evaluate the sum?

Comment: Please use $n$ ($k$ etc.) for a discrete (integer) summation variable, refer to it in the summation subscript, and reserve $x$ ($t$ etc.) for a continuous (real) variable, like everyone else. Your present notation is needlessly hard to read.

Comment: @JohnBentin Let me change the variable, but note that I used $x$ in other posts.

Comment: @JohnBentin The post is now “fixed”. Did I miss any “x”s?

Comment: You've overloaded "n" in the integrals in the formulas preceding the first figure. You're using $n$ as both the integration variable and as the integration limit. Also it's a bit confusing that you reference DLMF which is primarily about the non-normalized versions, but the question seems to be about the normalized versions. Are you sure all of the formulas you quote from DLMF apply to the normalized versions?

Comment: I am giving up on this one!

Comment: @StevenClark Yes they are all for the Normalized versions. I checked both numerically [here with the real part≈ .518](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum++i+fresnelF%28x%29%2BfresnelG%28x%29+from+0+to+4000) and [here with the Integral having the exact same value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%282+pi+sqrt+2%29sqrt%28t%29%281+%2B+EllipticTheta%283%2C++e%5E%28-%28%CF%80+t%29%2F2%29%29%29%2F%28%28t%5E2%2B1%29%29+from+0+to+infinity). I had to use n in the integral for the definition, for example Normalized S(x), $$\text S(n)=\int_0^n \sin\bigg(\frac{\pi x^2}2\bigg)dx$$

Comment: This is how you should have written the integrals in the formulas preceding the first figure. You went too far in converting $x$'s to $n$'s. The integration variable should be the continuous variable $x$, and the integration limit should be the integer value $n$. The first integral sum which corresponds to $i\,F(n)$ also seems to be missing a preceding $i$.

Comment: Your partial evaluation $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{1000} G(n)\approx 0.581217$ seems correct, but $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{1000} F(n)\approx 2.84118$ (I'm not sure how you came up with $3.41028$). Mathematica gives the following numerical evaluations: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty G(n)\approx 0.5812169998766582$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty F(n)\approx 7453.103433802164$, but generates a couple of error messages for the second evaluation.

Comment: @StevenClark The FresnelF sum almost certainly diverges. I just included it because I did not know it’s convergence until I found out when working on the question. Even with a few typos, the main idea of the question still stands. Thanks again.

Comment: @StevenClark You can also try to solve the equivalent $$\sum_{\Bbb N^0}\text G(n)= \frac1{2\sqrt2\pi}\int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\vartheta_3\left(e^{-\frac{\pi x}2}\right)\sqrt x}{x^2+1}dx +\frac14 $$ which uses a Jacobi Theta function [converging to $.5812…$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%282+pi+sqrt+2%29sqrt%28t%29%281+%2B+EllipticTheta%283%2C++e%5E%28-%28%CF%80+t%29%2F2%29%29%29%2F%28%28t%5E2%2B1%29%29+from+0+to+infinity). Thanks.

Comment: I thought the main idea was to evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty G(n)+i\,F(n)$. It's too bad if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty F(n)$ diverges because as you said $G(z)+i\,F(z)=e^{-\frac{1}{2} \pi i z^2} \int_z^{\infty } e^{\frac{1}{2} \pi i t^2}\,dt$ is a nice result.

Comment: @StevenClark Correct, but in the very end, that “nice result” would be a number with infinite magnitude: $.5812+…+ i\infty$, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263373/conjecture-lim-limits-x-to-infty-operatornamere-text-w-xx-mathop-limit). You can also evaluate the “nice result” if you want, but please separate the real and imaginary parts at the end. Thanks! Also see [DLMF 7.7.12](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7#E12). What do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130487/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-steven-clark).