# How to prove $ \sin x=...(1+\frac{x}{3\pi})(1+\frac{x}{2\pi})(1+\frac{x}{\pi})(1-\frac{x}{3\pi})(1-\frac{x}{2\pi})(1-\frac{x}{\pi})...$?

Tags: trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [infinite product of sine function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157372/infinite-product-of-sine-function)

> Here is an other one which is more or less what Euler did in one of his proofs.

> The function sinx where x∈R is zero exactly at x=nπ for each integer n. If we factorized it as an infinite product we get

How to prove
$$
\sin x=...(1+\frac{x}{3\pi})(1+\frac{x}{2\pi})(1+\frac{x}{\pi})x(1-\frac{x}{3\pi})(1-\frac{x}{2\pi})(1-\frac{x}{\pi})...
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of Edmund Landau, from his Differential and Integral Calculus.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have that book, and which part of a usual book on Mathematical Analysis  could I find the proof in,like Zorich's 《Mathematical Analysis》 or ГригорийМихайлович Фихтенгольц‘s 《Calculus course》. I mean what topic it is included in?

Comment: I need theorem 233

Comment: @LucasZanella You can google the book, it is called "Differential and Integral Calculus" by Edmund Landau.

Comment: @Miao (Probably very late, but) Fichtenholz has a (IMO much nicer) proof of this fact in Vol. 2 Art. 408. When reading it, it helps to remember that sinc x = sin x / x appears in the [Whittaker interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula), and that the analogous interpolation formula for functions on a circle involves things like sin(2n+1)x / sin x instead, compare also [this summation formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro).

Comment: I like this proof very much. It looks very similar to Herglotz's trick, which is explained in the chapter "Cotangent and the Herglotz trick
" from Proofs from the book. Landau uses a limit process (very roughly, considering the values at $(x+k)/2^n$ and letting $n \to \infty$). Herglotz uses only $x/2$ and $(x+1)/2$, I wonder if it's possible to do something similar here.