# Having trouble re-arranging

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am struggling to remember what I need to do/can do to reduce this further, and searching hasn't helped much, probably since I am not sure how to word the problem correctly. Anyway, I am attempting to re-arrange this function to solve for x:

$$
n=\frac{sin(2x)}{2}-x
$$

I'm thinking that I am just forgetting some simple thing, but it's been a while since I had to do any real math.

Comment: Are you solving for $x$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: @m1cky22 yes. n is composed of other known constants, so I simplified it for this question.

Comment: This might be relevant http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/QQ.09.00/roble1.html

Comment: @m1cky22 Thanks a ton! I was beginning to wonder if it was iteratively calculated. Wolfram could give me numerical results, but no solution. I can write a program to do what I need with "good enough" accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve it explicitly in terms of elementary functions.  If you know $x$ is small, you can expand $\sin (2x) \approx 2x - \frac 1{3!}(2x)^3 + \frac 1{5!}(2x)^5 + \ldots$.  The first term cancels with the $-x$ you have, so you get $n \approx \frac 86x^3, x \approx \sqrt[3]{\frac 34 n}$.  If $n$ is rather large, you can use that $-\frac 12 \le \frac {\sin (2x)}2 \le \frac 12$ so $x \approx -n$ and do some root finding from there.

Comment: Unfortunately, x will be anywhere from 0 to Pi. Interesting solution nonetheless, thank you.

Comment: Then you are into one dimensional root finding, which is what Alpha is doing.  There are chapters in all numerical analysis texts.  I like [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html)  chapter 9, which is free on line.

Comment: Source:  The power series of sin(x) is defined when asking the following question.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347648/infinite-factorization-power-series-of-sinx    To prevent confusion for those on an algebra, precalculus level it's probably easier to accept the need for numerical, nonexact answers.