# How to prove that $\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2})$

Tags: complex-analysis, products, infinite-product

How to prove that $$\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$$

I tried it with the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ but I failed.

Is there any help?

Comment: This is a prime example of the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem, although you may be looking for a more elementary proof than this.

Comment: @EricAuld thanks but it is not clear for me and it is better if there is another one :)

Comment: You should check out _Journey Through Genius_ by William Dunham. He goes through the intuition behind this factorization when Euler (?) did it but when it was first realized, there was little to no rigor to the arguments. The "proof" he presents that Euler used is good enough to get the idea, though.

Comment: You should probably read this excellent article :-)

http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/07/13/eulers-nonstandard-nonsense/

Comment: I saw the beautiful and interesting answer in Journey Through Genius but is there another answer ?

Comment: Euler argued that because $\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}$ has roots at $x = \pm1, \pm2, \pm3, ...$, the Factor theorem allows you to write $\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x} = (1 - x)(1 + x)(2 - x)(2 + x)...(n - x)(n + x)... = (1 - x^2)(2^2 - x^2)...(n^2 - x^2)... = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2})$.

Comment: Have you tried taking logs and differentiating ? See what happens... I don't know if this will lead anywhere; just a thought.

Comment: + [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/215966/73025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from the identity

> $$ \frac{\pi \cot(\pi x)}{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-n^2} \quad x\neq \mathbb{Z}$$

$$ \implies \frac{\pi \cot(\pi x)}{x}= \frac{1}{x^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-n^2}$$

$$ \implies {\pi \cot(\pi x)}= \frac{1}{x}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^2-n^2}. $$

Now, you can advance by integrating both sides w.r.t. $x$.