# Prove that $\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{x}{\pi n}\right) \left(\frac{x}{\pi n}+1\right)=\sin(x)/x$

Tags: reference-request, infinite-product

Would anyone know of a reference where the following is proved, or how best to prove it? This can be checked with Mathematica, but how about a proof?

$$\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{x}{\pi  n}\right) \left(1+\frac{x}{\pi  n}\right)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

Comment: The original derivation by Euler was slightly unrigorous, a modern and "elementary" proof can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323296523_Euler's_Sine_Product_Formula_An_Elementary_Proof)

Comment: related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157372/938462) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/215963/938462)

Comment: Thank you both for the references. Exactly what I was looking for.