# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{r=1}^n\frac{4r^2}{4r^2+1}=\;?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{r=1}^n\frac{4r^2}{4r^2+1}$$

Please solve this question. I am unable to solve this.

(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciJ2T.jpg).)

Comment: This image is really really hard to read.  Please re-type it in TeX.

Comment: You may want to check [*this*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Infinite_product_formulae).

Comment: Why do people vote to close this?  It seems a reasonable question, reasonable enough not to downvote and close IMO.

Answer (score 4):

One may recall the [infinite product of the $\sin$ function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157372/infinite-product-of-sine-function/157378#157378) which yields
$$
\frac{\sinh x}{x}=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right),
\quad x\neq0,
$$ then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{r=1}^n\frac{4r^2}{4r^2+1}=\left(\prod\limits_{r=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{4 r^2}\right)\right)^{-1}=\frac{\pi}{e^{\pi/2}-e^{-\pi/2}}.
$$

Comment: Perfectly simple.  +1