# Product $\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{4 (\pi n-x) (\pi n+x)}{\pi ^2 n^2-4 x^2}}$

Tags: calculus

$$\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{4 (\pi  n-x) (\pi  n+x)}{\pi ^2 n^2-4 x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt[4]{1+e^{-2 i x}} \sqrt[4]{1+e^{2 i x}}}$$
Mathematica Could not  find the solution it is possible to show?.

Comment: where did you get this from? what work have you done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall the [Weierstrass product of the sine function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157372/infinite-product-of-sine-function)
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right),
\qquad x\in(0,\pi),
$$ then one may write, for appropriate values of $x$,
$$
\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{4 (\pi  n-x) (\pi  n+x)}{\pi ^2 n^2-4 x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\prod _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)}{\prod _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)}}=\sqrt{\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x}}{\frac{\sin (2x)}{2x}}}=\frac1{\sqrt{\cos x}}.
$$