# Evaluate the product $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{2^{1999}} (4\sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{2^{2000}})-3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, products, trigonometric-series

Evaluate the product $$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{2^{1999}} \left(4\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2^{2000}}\right)-3\right)$$
I tried by making it into $\frac{\sin 3\theta}{\sin\theta}$ form but couldn’t proceed like that, so I wrote the series reversed and multiplied both in the hope of some symmetry but couldn’t observe anything. Please give some ideas on how to work on it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604421/find-value-of-prod-k-021999-left4-sin2-left-frack-pi22000-ri?