# Euler's product expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Can you help me to prove  the following formula $$ \frac{\sin (\pi x )}{\pi x} = \prod\limits_{n \geq 1} \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2}\right) ? $$

Thank you so much!

Comment: That's in every decent textbook. MSE isn't a replacement, it's about when you don't get what the textbook says, and ask about the specific problem.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thank you so much! In fact, it is a formula in my course, but I can not find a reference of its proof. Can you help me to share such one?

Comment: @mathJuan might be of some [help](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/9b72f7074d8a7da75376fe6bb2b1c40410eea0b0) , and this as [well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)

Comment: Another [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3599343) thing I met recently.

Answer (score 4):

Quick proof (not giving the details as you can find them in any textbook talking about the subject) :
$$ \forall z\in\mathbb{C},\left(1+\frac{iz}{2p+1}\right)^{2p+1}-\left(1-\frac{iz}{2p+1}\right)^{2p+1}=2iz\prod_{k=1}^p\left(1-\frac{z^2}{(2p+1)^2\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2p+1}\right)}\right) $$
Taking the limit as $p\rightarrow +\infty$ gives
$$ e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=2iz\prod_{k\geqslant 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right) $$
and thus $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(z)}{z}=\prod_{k\geqslant 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a great hint for me!